# How to ignore posts in pre_get_posts?

Tags: functions, query, pre-get-posts

I'm using `pre_get_posts` and looking for a way to exclude posts in the main query. I'm using `query_vars` to query posts from a specific category and looking for a solution to exclude those posts in the main query.

My code:

```
// function to setup query_vars
function ctrl_dly_podcast( $query_vars ){
  $query_vars[] = 'ctrl_podcasts_status';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'ctrl_dly_podcast' );
function index_first_post( $query_vars ){
  $query_vars[] = 'index_first_post';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'index_first_post' );
function first_video( $query_vars ){
  $query_vars[] = '1st_video';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'first_video' );
function rest_posts( $query_vars ){
  $query_vars[] = 'posts_the_rest';
  return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'rest_posts' );


//the pre_get_posts function
function opby_query( $query ) {
if( isset( $query->query_vars['ctrl_podcasts_status'] )) {
    $query->set('tax_query', array(array('taxonomy' => 'category','field' => 'slug','terms' => array( 'podcast-control-daily' ),'operator'=> 'IN')));
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
}
if( isset( $query->query_vars['index_first_post'] )) {
    $query->set('tax_query', array(array('taxonomy' => 'category','field' => 'slug','terms' => array( 'podcast-control-daily' ),'operator'=> 'NOT IN'),array('taxonomy' => 'post_format','field' => 'slug','terms' => array( 'video' ),'operator'=> 'NOT IN')));
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
}
if( isset( $query->query_vars['1st_video'] )) {
    $query->set('tax_query', array(array('taxonomy' => 'category','field' => 'slug','terms' => array( 'video' ),'operator'=> 'IN')));
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
};
// the part I'm having problems with
if( isset( $query->query_vars['posts_the_rest'] )) {
    $query->set('offset', array($query->query_vars['1st_video'],$query->query_vars['index_first_post'],$query->query_vars['ctrl_podcasts_status']);
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 15);
}
return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'opby_query' );
```

Comment: excluding things this way is extremely slow and heavy on the database. It's much faster to ask for posts in eery single category ( without mentioning category X ), then it is to tell the database you don't want categry X. Exclusions involve the creation of temporary database tables and full table copies and a full table scan, the scaling and performance cost of such a query can be massive.

Comment: Also, don't double post questions to get more traffic, it's spammy and will get you shadow banned by the automated anti-spam systems. ( it can see your deleted questions, as can moderators )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be better:

So in `pre_get_posts`, I've setup a `get_posts` function to get IDs of posts and then pass them on to `post_not_in` and `offset` the first post from the loop.

```
function site_alerts( $query_vars ){
   $query_vars[] = 'opby_alerts';
   return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'site_alerts' );
function opby_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $exclude = get_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'candlestick-episode', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $exclude2 = get_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 15);
    $query->set( 'offset', '1' );
    $query->set('post__not_in',array($exclude[0],$exclude2[0])); 
}
if( isset( $query->query_vars['opby_alerts'] )) {
    $query->set('post_type', array( 'alerts' ) );
    $query->set('meta_query', array('relation' => 'OR',array('key' => 'breaking_news_status','value' => 'active'),array('key' => 'developing_news_status','value' => 'active'),array('key' => 'alert_news_status','value' => 'active'),array('key' => 'notice_news_status','value' => 'active')));
    $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
}
return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'opby_query' );
```

And then the posts that are in `post_not_in` have their own query:

```
// first loop to show the first post from the offset
<?php $args = array('posts_per_page' => '1','tax_query' => array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('candlestick-episode','candlestick-special','video'),
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
)
)
);$query = new WP_query ( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); /* start the loop */ ?>
first - <?php the_title(); ?><br>
<?php // End the loop.
endwhile;
rewind_posts();
} ?>

// first post from a category that's in post__not_in
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => '1','tax_query' => array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('candlestick-episode','candlestick-special'),
    'operator' => 'IN'
)
)
);$query = new WP_query ( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); /* start the loop */ ?>
podcast - <?php the_title(); ?><br>
<?php // End the loop.
endwhile;
rewind_posts();
} ?>

// another post from category from post__not_in
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => '1','tax_query' => array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('video'),
    'operator' => 'IN'
)
)
);$query = new WP_query ( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); /* start the loop */ ?>
video - <?php the_title(); ?><br>
<?php // End the loop.
endwhile;
rewind_posts();
} ?>

// the loop from pre_get_posts
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<?php the_title(); ?><br>
<?php // End the loop.
endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```php
function opby_query( $query ) {

    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( $query->is_home() ) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 15);
        };
        if ( isset( $query->query_vars['ctrl_podcasts_status'] ) ) {
            // get main query args
            $subquery_args = $query->query_vars;
            // add tax_query filter
            $subquery_args['tax_query'] = array( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'podcast-control-daily' ),
                'operator'=> 'IN'
            ) );
            // get only the first post
            $subquery_args['posts_per_page'] = 1;
            // we need only post IDs
            $subquery_args['fields'] = 'ids';
            // run the subquery
            $exclude_posts = get_posts( $subquery_args );
            if ( is_array( $exclude_posts ) ) {
                $query->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude_posts );
            }
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work. I've updated the code above to show a better working example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this one?

```
$query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 1, 1 ) );
```

In the array( 1, 1 ) is array( $PostID, $PostID ) which post ids you want to exclude from main query.